# Replacing the operand of an LLVM instruction

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm

In the following code, I try to replace operand(s) of an LLVM instructions. However it doesn't work and nothing is changed. Any idea how to solve this?

```
for (OI = insn->op_begin(), OE = insn->op_end(); OI != OE; ++OI)
{
    Value *val = *OI;
    iter = mapClonedAndOrg.find( val );

    if( iter != mapClonedAndOrg.end( ) )
    {
        // Here I try to replace the operand, to no effect!
        val = (Value*)iter->second.PN;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the iterator `OI` to replace it, instead of the local pointer `val`. So it should be like this.

```
for (OI = insn->op_begin(), OE = insn->op_end(); OI != OE; ++OI)
{
    Value *val = *OI;
    iter = mapClonedAndOrg.find( val );

    if( iter != mapClonedAndOrg.end( ) )
    {
        *OI = (Value*)iter->second.PN;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is simply making a local pointer point to something else, you don't actually change *what* it points to. For that you need to use the dereferencing operator `*`:

```
*val = *((Value*) iter->second.PN);
```

Comment: Well this doesn't work in context of LLVM, infact it doesn't even compile, as = operator is private member of Value class. In LLVM, what I think is that every operand is linked to the instruction through a pointer, so just changing the pointer should replace the operand, but anyhow that is also not working, so I'm not really sure what is the right way to solve this. At least it worked for me for other things like instructions, but for operands the same method is not working.

Comment: @user1018562 You can't change the pointer `val`, as that will just make the _local_ variable `val` point to something else. A possible solution then might be to change the _iterator_: `*OI = (Value*) iter->second.PN;`